# What is meant by Coq arrow -> in Coq theorem?

Tags: coq

I am trying to understand Coq theorem:

```
Theorem thm0 : UseCl Pos (PredVP (UsePN john_PN) walk_V) ->
               UseCl Pos (PredVP (UsePN john_PN) walk_V).
intro H.
exact H.
Qed.
```

from https://github.com/GU-CLASP/FraCoq/blob/master/Tutorial.org

What is meant by the arrow symbol `->`? As I understand, then Coq uses two arrows https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Basics.html : 1) double arrow for defining type constructors and 2) single arrow `->` for definint new type. But this theorem is statement, not the type definition. Why there is this arrow? How to understand this statement as a Coq theorem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The double arrow (`=>`) is used in Coq to mark pattern-matching branches.  For example, we can define boolean negation like this:

```
Definition negb (b : bool) : bool :=
  match b with
  | true  => false
  | false => true
  end.
```

The single arrow (`->`) is used to express two seemingly unrelated concepts:

1. Function types. For instance, `nat -> bool` is the type of functions from the natural numbers to booleans.
2. *Logical implication*. This is the use that you see in the statement of your theorem. The statement `A -> B` means that `B` holds whenever `A` does.

In reality, however, this distinction is only superficial: in Coq, proofs of implication and functions are actually the same thing! For Coq, a proof of implication `A -> B` is, in a precise sense, a function that takes a proof asserting the truth of `A` and returns a proof asserting the truth of `B`.  If this sounds confusing, do not worry: you can just pretend most of the time that the two uses of the arrow refer to different things, and this will not harm you. The Software Foundations book has a [chapter](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/ProofObjects.html) that discusses these issues in more detail.

Comment: Additionally, @TomR, you will also eventually realize that a "theorem statement" *is* the definition of a type. This goes alongside with Arthur's answer that function types and logical implications are the same concept. So, while for now, there seems to be a semantic distinction between something like `bool` (looks like a type) and something like `forall (b : bool), b = true \/ b = false` (looks like a theorem statement), you will eventually be able to consider both as, simultaneously, types and theorem statements.